# Geometric interpretation of Hölder's inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, intuition, integral-inequality, geometric-interpretation

Is there a geometric intuition for Hölder's inequality?

I am referring to $||fg||_1 \le ||f||_p ||f||_q $, when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

For $p=q=2$ this is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, for which I have geometric intution: The projection of a vector along a direction shortens its length.

My question is if there is a similar geometric interpretation for Hölder's inequality. I am aware of the [scaling argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1231827/104576), which shows the inequality can only hold when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$; but why should we expect this to be true when the $p,q$ are conjugates? Perhaps there is some physical interpretation?

Note that I am looking for intuition, not necessarily a formal proof. Hölder's inequality can be proved using Young's inequality, for which a beautiful intuition is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149903/104576).

In my perspective, even though this gives intuition to a *component in the proof* of Hölder's inequality, this does not really give an intuition for the inequality *itself*.

(But maybe I am wrong? does the actual integration have "true content" in it, or is Hölder really nothing but Young's inequality in disguise? Part of the confusion is that the intuition for Young's inequality [is based on integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149903/104576), so if we only rely on that, the intuition for Hölder should be some sort of "double integration"...  )

To see that the geometric intuition of Young's and Hölder's inequalities are somewhat different, we can look at $p=q=2$:

In that case, Young's inequality is just the standard AM-GM inequality for two variables. This inequality [can be interpreted geometrically](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt669/student.folders/callinan.michael/Essays/Essay2/Essay27.gif). Although here one can also view this as "projection only shortens", the scenario is a little different than the one in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. (At least the the reasons behind the "equality cases" seem slightly different to me).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Before getting to intuition: you've mention the proof by Young's inequality, but there is another nice proof that is a direct application of Jensen's inequality. Assume $\|f\|_p=\|g\|_q=1$ and $f,g>0.$ Then $(\int fg)^p=[\int g^q(fg^{1-q})]^p\leq \int g^q(fg^{1-q})^p=\int f^p=1.$ The inequality comes from the convexity of $x^p$ and probability measure $d\mu=g^qdx.$)

In any Banach space $V$ there is an inequality $|\langle x,f\rangle|\leq \|x\|_V \|f\|_{V^*}.$ This is almost a triviality, but it is a reflection of the geometrical fact that unit balls are convex. Vectors in the dual space $V^*$ represent hyperplanes that support the unit ball in $V.$

From the viewpoint of the geometry of Banach spaces, the intuition behind Hölder's inequality is that the dual space of $L^p$ has an integral representation as $L^q.$ If you take a point $f_0$ on the $L^p$ unit sphere, the supporting hyperplane is $\{f\mid\int fg=1\}$ where $g=\overline{f_0}|f_0|^{p-2},$ or simply $g=f_0^{p-1}$ with the assumption $f_0>0.$ For $\|f\|_p=1$ we get $\int fg\leq 1,$ which is Hölder's inequality.

Even if you had no idea what the dual space of $L^p$ might be, it would be natural to derive the convexity inequality $f^p\geq f_0^p+pf_0^{p-1}(f-f_0)$ - this is the equation for the supporting hyperplane at $x=f_0$ on the curve $x\mapsto x^p.$ Integrating gives $\int f^p\geq \int f_0^p+p\int f_0^{p-1}(f-f_0),$ which is a type of supporting hyperplane equation in $L^p.$ Rearranging and setting $f_0=g^{1/(p-1)}$ gives $\int f^p+(p-1)\int g^q\geq p\int fg,$ which is Hölder's inequality, after scaling to get $\|f\|_p=\|g\|_q=1.$ This argument is just Young's inequality in disguise but I hope the appearance of $q$ seems quite natural here.

For all these kinds of inequalities it is worth reading https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/amplification-arbitrage-and-the-tensor-power-trick/ if you haven't already.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand something: what happens in the inequality step in $(\int fg)^p=[\int g^q(fg_{1-q})]^p\leq \int g^q(fg_{1-q})^p=\int f^p=1$? I guess $g_{1-q}$ is supposed to be $g^{1-q}$. The inequality is supposed to be $[\int g^q(fg_{1-q})]^p\leq \int g^{pq}(fg^{1-q})^p$, no?

Comment: @AsafShachar: Jensen's inequality for the probability measure $g^qdx$ gives $(\int g^q(\dots))^p\leq \int g^q(\dots)^p.$ (There's a more careful version at the bottom of the section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality#Proof_of_Hölder's_inequality or in Lieb and Loss "Analysis")

Comment: I don't understand " but it is a reflection of the geometrical fact that unit balls are convex. " ? How are the two related ? I think it is due to the way $||f||_{V^*}$ is defined and the linearity of $f$ and the norm on $V$.